# Why mysqldump is going so big?

Tags: mysql

Scenario:

MySQL database with mostly MyISAM tables. Current weight of MySQL filesystem:

```
80K ./casin_emails
212K    ./performance_schema
371M    ./casin_info
32K ./percona
572K    ./casin
1.1M    ./mysql
67G .
```

as you noticed most of the space comes from ibdata files

```
17956960  67G -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  67G Nov 11 11:45 ibdata1
17956940 5.0M -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M Nov 11 11:45 ib_logfile0
17956939 5.0M -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M Nov 11 10:44 ib_logfile1
```

at the moment of write this question the still running process of mysqldump is writing a file of 14 GBytes.

So my question maybe is obvious. Why mysqldump is creating so big file if the current spaces of databases are so small? is ibdata guilty about that?

I suppose I cannot avoid the fact that mysqldump needs to generate some kind of backup of the data on ibadata but I just want to be sure and know why this is happening.

Thanks!

PS: I've searched previously about this question but all posts I found were about how to shrink databases which are not my current question.

Comment: This link might be helpful https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/08/20/why-is-the-ibdata1-file-continuously-growing-in-mysql/

Comment: `mysqldump` genenerates SQL queries which are verbose by the nature of the SQL language.

Answer (score 3):

As MySQL documentation on [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) says (highlighting is mine):

> The mysqldump client utility performs logical backups, producing a **set of SQL statements** that can be executed to reproduce the original database object definitions and table data.

So, mysqldump does not simply export the data, but wrps them into sql statements. Moreover, all data is exported as text, so every numeric data and nulls will take up a lot more space, than in the database.

Comment: I understand all your points but if mysqldump makes **"set of SQL statements"**, if the size of databases is 371M the heaviest   (./casin_info)...is all the data related to this SQL statements? Or ibdata has also to say about that? Because I still don't understand how so small database (300 M) or less can generate a .sql file of Gb of magnitude. I don't know if you see my point here...

Comment: ibdata1 is the default file name for the innodb table space, so that would hold all the data in the innodb tables.